# Moving (not adding) a GFI protected outlet (that isn't the GFI outlet)

Tags: electrical, wiring

Odd scenario in that I need to move a GFI protected outlet (downstream of the actual GFI outlet) about 10" (to accommodate new bathroom cabinets/countertop). Unfortunately, the existing wiring is too snug to just snake it to the new outlet location - so my question is - can I just add new wiring (same rating) to extend the wiring the 10" to the new outlet location? This would NOT add load to the circuit as there would still only be the one (downstream) outlet.

Also, I don't need to remove the old junction box - so the connection to the new wiring would be with wire nuts that would be inside the original junction box (with the new wiring just going to the new box/outlet).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No problem doing this, except for one thing: **The old junction box must remain accessible.**

It can be inside a cabinet (i.e., open a door to get to it), but it can't be blocked by a permanently installed cabinet, covered over with wallpaper or drywall, etc.

Comment: Put a blank cover on the old box and you will be fine as this answer says. It’s always a good idea to verify the proper polarity and if 3 wire test the GFCI circuit from the new location, if 2 wire the test button on the circuit tester won’t work because there is no ground this is not a problem just use the test and reset on the GFCI device itself to verify operation 1 a month.